# Continuity of the operator "inverse of" in the space of linear, bounded and bijective operators

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

Let $(X,\|\ \|_X),(Y,\|\ \|_Y)$ be two Banach spaces over $K$.

> **Definition:**
>   
> **$\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad I(X,Y):=\big\{A\in \mathscr B(X,Y):A\text{  is invertible and  }A^{-1}\in\mathscr B(Y,X)\big\}$**
>   
>  where $\mathscr B(X,Y)$ is de space of bounded linear operators between $X$ and $Y$.

Lets define $\mathscr U:I(X,Y)\to I(Y,X)$ given by
$$
\mathscr U(A)=A^{-1}
$$
I want to prove that **$\mathscr U$ is continuous**.

I'm really lost trying to figure out a way for this one. I came up with the idea of a sequence $(A_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}\subset I(X,Y)$ that converged to some $A\in I(X,Y)$ but realized that $\mathscr U(A_n)$ may not always converge. Another attempt was to show that $\mathscr U$ is bounded and linear but $I(X,Y),I(Y,X)$ are not even subspaces, since the sum of invertible operators is not always invertible. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Consider the following fact: if $A:X \rightarrow Y$ is a bounded linear operator and $\|A\| < 1$, then $I-A \in I(X,Y)$ and $$(I-A)^{-1} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty A^n.$$ Using this, one can establish that if $A \in I(X,Y)$, then for every bounded linear operator $B:X \rightarrow Y$, the relation $\|B-A\| < \|A^{-1}\|^{-1}$ implies $B \in I(X,Y)$. For in this case, we have $$\|I-A^{-1}B\|\leqq \|A^{-1}\|\|A-B\| <1,$$ so that $B= A[I-(I-A^{-1}B)] \in I(X,Y)$.

Fix $A \in I(X,Y)$ arbitrarily. If $B$ is a bounded linear operator and $\|B\| < \|A^{-1}\|^{-1}$, then $$\|-BA^{-1}\|=\|BA^{-1}\|\leqq\|B\|\|A^{-1}\|<1.$$ Thus, $A+B=[I-(-BA^{-1})]A \in I(X,Y)$. This also allows us to apply the fact I cited in the beggining (with $-BA^{-1}$ instead of $A$) to obtain $$\|(A+B)^{-1} - A^{-1}\| =\| A^{-1}(I-(-BA^{-1}))^{-1} - A^{-1}\| =\Bigg\| A^{-1} \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-BA^{-1})^n  - A^{-1}\Bigg\| =\Bigg\| A^{-1}\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-BA^{-1})^n \Bigg\| \leqq \|A^{-1}\|\sum_{n=1}^\infty(\|B\|\|A^{-1}\|)^n = \frac{\|B\|\|A^{-1}\|^2}{1-\|B\|\|A^{-1}\|}. $$ Letting $\|B\| \rightarrow 0$, it follows that $(A+B)^{-1} \rightarrow A^{-1}$ and the continuity of ${\scr U}$ at $A$ is proved.

**Note:** This fact I mentioned at the beggining really uses the completeness of $(Y,\|\|_Y)$. It uses that every absolutely convergent series in ${\scr B}(X,Y)$ converges, which is equivalent to the completeness of ${\scr B}(X,Y)$, which in turn is equivalent to the completeness of $Y$.

Comment: Sorry, I've been trying, but I get lost trying to understand this. I don't know where does $(I-A)^{-1}=\sum_{n\in\Bbb N} A^n$ comes from and cant go further from the proposition that $$\|B-A\|<\|A^{-1}\|^{-1}\Rightarrow\;B\in I(X,Y)$$

Comment: First of all, note that since $\|A^n\|≦\|A\|^n, n=1,2,3,...,$ and $\|A\|<1$, it follows that $\sum \|A^n\|$ converges. To say that $Y$ is complete is the same as to say that an absolutely convergent series in $Y$ converges. Hence, $\sum A^n$ converges. Since $(I−A)\sum_{n=0}^N A^n=I−A^{N+1}=(\sum_{n=0}^N A^n)(I−A)$ and $A^{N+1} \rightarrow 0$, as $N \rightarrow \infty$, the fact about $(I-A)^{-1}$ should now be clear.

Comment: As for "$\|B-A\|<\|A^{-1}\|^{-1}$ implies $B \in I(X,Y)$", it is justified right away, when I go on saying "For in this case ...".

Comment: Sorry for the delay Yuri, but I'm taking this process step by step to get it whole. Ok, we're taking any $A\in \mathscr B(X,Y)$ with $\|A\|<1$ so that $\sum A^n$ converges. Now, how can I show that this result implies that $\sum A^n = (I-A)^{-1}$. I see that $(I-A)\sum_{n=0}^N A^n=I-A^{N+1}$, but can't see how $A^{N+1}\to 0$ as $N\to\infty$

Comment: Is it the fact that $\sum A^n$ converges that makes $(A^n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converge to zero as in the sequence of real numbers?

Comment: Put $S_N := \sum_{n=0}^N A^n, N=0,1,2,3,...$. Then $(S_N)_{N=0}^\infty$ is a convergent sequence, hence it is a Cauchy sequence. Given $\epsilon > 0$, there is some $N_0$ for which $M\geqq N \geqq N_0$ imply $\|S_M-S_N\|<\epsilon.$ Thus, if $N \geqq N_0$, then $\|A^{N+1}\|=\|S_{N+1} -S_N\| < \epsilon.$ You can see some of these general properties about series in a normed space in Dieudonné's 'Foundations of Modern Analysis', for instance.

Comment: Ok, got this part, thanks! I got stucked following your proof that $\|B-A\|<\|A^{-1}\|$ implies $B\in I(X,Y)$. I get the fact that, since $\|I-A^{-1}B\|<1$, $[I-(I-A^{-1}B)]\in I(X,Y)$, but why $A[I-(I-A^{-1}B)]\in I(X,Y)$?

Comment: Because $I(X,Y)$ is stable under composition: if $A \in I(X,Y)$ and $B \in I(X,Y)$, then $AB \in I(X,Y)$ (the inverse of $AB$ is $B^{-1}A^{-1}$). (I should say that when I call a bounded linear map 'invertible' I already mean its inverse is bounded.)

Comment: Oh, I see, thanks! I'm just one more little detail to get it whole: So when you take any $A\in I(X,Y)$, fixed, you take $B\in\mathscr B(X,Y)$ s.t. $\|B\|<\frac{1}{\|A^{-1}\|}$, which gives you the whole argument to conclude the continuity of $\mathscr U$, but how can you guarantee such $B$ for any $A$ we take in $I(X,Y)$?

Comment: I fixed $A$, and proceeded to show that ${\scr U}$ is continuous at $A$. So given $\epsilon>0$, we had to find $\delta>0$ for which $\|T^{-1} - A^{-1}\|<\epsilon$ provided that $T \in I(X,Y)$ and $\|T-A\|<\delta$. Writing $T = A+B$, where $B=T-A$, one promptly sees that this is equivalent to show that $\|(A+B)^{-1} -A^{-1}\|<\epsilon$ if $A+B \in I(X,Y)$ and $\|B\|=\|T-A\|<\delta$. So I start off assuming $\delta \leqq \|A^{-1}\|$. At the end I concluded that we can make $\delta$ even smaller (that's the ''letting $\|B\| \rightarrow 0$'' part) so that $\|(A+B)^{-1}-B^{-1}\|<\epsilon$, say.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks a lot Yuri! Really good one!