# Operator inversion is continuous

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $L(X)$ be the set of continuous linear operators on $X$. Let $\Omega \subseteq L(X)$ be the set of invertible linear operators.$\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\lVert#1\rVert}$

> For $\Phi \in \Omega$, $\Phi \mapsto \Phi^{-1}$ is continuous.

Proof:

Let $\Phi,\Psi \in \Omega$ and $\epsilon > 0$. If $\norm{\Phi - \Psi} < \delta$, observe that
$$ \norm{\Phi^{-1} - \Psi^{-1}} \leq \norm{\Phi^{-1}}\norm{\Phi - \Psi}\norm{\Psi^{-1}} < \norm{\Phi^{-1}}\norm{\Psi^{-1}}\delta
$$
Defining $\delta = \epsilon/\norm{\Psi^{-1}}$ converts the inequality to $\norm{\Psi^{-1}}\epsilon$, but how to show that $\norm{\Psi^{-1}}$ is bounded "near" $\Phi$?

Comment: There might be a direct proof, but one way to prove this is with Neumann series.  See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1757371/continuity-of-the-operator-inverse-of-in-the-space-of-linear-bounded-and-bije?rq=1).