# Prove $\phi: GL(X) \to GL(X)$ where $\phi(A)= A^{-1}$ is continuous ($X$ is a Banach space)

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm taking a Functional Analysis course, and in one of the lectures we proved the two following theorems, after which the third was stated as "one can show that..." -- but I'm unable to show it.

The two statements are:

1. $GL(X)$ is open in $B(X)$ (bounded from Banach space $X$ to itself)
2. (a lemma used to prove 1): For all $A \in B(X)$, if $||A||<1$ then $I-A$ is invertible, and $(I-A)^{-1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty A^n$

After these two, he said that it can be proven that the map between $GL(X)$ to itself, which maps $A$ to its inverse $A^{-1}$ is continuous.
After several attempts, I've concluded (perhaps wrongly) that the best way to approach this is by trying to prove the following statement (continuity at every point):

Let $A_0 \in GL(X)$ and let $\epsilon>0$. Then we are looking for a $\delta>0$ such that if $||A-A_0||<\delta$ then $||A^{-1}-A_0^{-1}||<\epsilon$.

I have tried using the openness (1) by using the radius found during the proof, which is (**) $r:=\frac{1}{||A^{-1}||}$ (i.e. $B_{r}(A) \subseteq GL(X)$ for any $A \in GL(X)$), but this did not lead anywhere. I also tried thinking of writing $||A^{-1}-A_0^{-1}||$ somehow as a function of $A-A_0$ but that hasn't been fruitful either.

**EDIT**
Another idea: perhaps
$$||A^{-1}-{A_0}^{-1}||=
||(A-{A_0})^{-1}||<\frac{1}{||A-A_0||}$$
where the inequality follows from (**) above with $A-{A_0}$ instead of $A$, and then take $\delta=\frac{1}{\epsilon}$? But how can I justify the first equality?

How can I prove this given that the only available related theorems I can use are the former two? (and perhaps other elementary concepts I'm probably missing).

Thanks.

Comment: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1757371/continuity-of-the-operator-inverse-of-in-the-space-of-linear-bounded-and-bije?rq=1, does this help?

Comment: Yes, thank you. If someone has a way to continue my line of thought (using epsilon-delta) would love to know. I'm assuming it would be in the same lines of what's in this link, but can't yet see it.